# Bing Web Search Code works in console app but not MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bing-api

I'my trying to use the Bing Search API in my MVC project. What's odd is that when I run it through a console application I get the expected results, however when I try to run it online I get no results when I step into the program and look at the value for the variable imageResults. I do see a message `TotalCount = 'imageResults.TotalCount' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException.'` My controller is listed below.

```
namespace MusicMan.Controllers
{
    public class BingSearchController : Controller
    {

        // GET: BingSearch
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string search)
        {
            var bingContainer = new Bing.BingSearchContainer(
                new Uri("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/"));

            // Replaced the value with my account key.
            var accountKey = "mykey";

            // Configures bingContainer to use your credentials.
            bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(accountKey, accountKey);

            // Build the query.
            var imageQuery =
                bingContainer.Image("xbox", null, null, null, null, null, null);

            var imageResults = imageQuery.Execute();

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on why it works as a console app but not MVC would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any reason accountKey is being used twice in the NetworkCredentials constructor?

Comment: The documentation and example code listed on the Bing website for the API always showed it that way.

Comment: Don't see the line of code that has the error. TotalCount = imageResults.TotalCount

Comment: I know that's part of what is so odd, I never make a call to TotalCount

Comment: Something in your view?

Comment: Hi Bryan, Any luck with this issue ...I have the same problem...Thx